# Neovim marks all closing brackets inside a :heredoc as red

Tags: lua, neovim

As described I am faced with the following problem:

Closing brackets inside a `heredoc` block inside my init.vim are marked as red and I am presented with the following error:

`E5107: Error loading lua [string ":lua"]:57: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 55) near ':'`

For my full config please see: https://github.com/mxngls/dotfiles/blob/main/init.vim

[image]

Comment: it means you forgot to close a bracket, check the line that the error message is presented to you

Comment: I just checked but I can't see where. The setup is copied from https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp

Comment: the error message mentioned `line 55`. please post the full conf.

Comment: Please see the link to the corresponding github repo in the question. :)

Comment: check line 142 on your config, you have an additional `:` out of nowhere

Comment: Fixed the typo. Unfortunately that wasn't it. Almost all closing brackets, even the one covering a ```require``` statement are marked in red.